# Trying to find a complete list of git variables

Tags: git

I've seen references in other questions to various git variables such as:

- GIT_CURL_VERBOSE
- GIT_SHELL

How can I get a complete list of config variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The git man page (`man git` and search for `^ENVIRONMENT`) has a list of environment variables.

As of version 1.7.9.5, there are 24 of them. (`GIT_SHELL` is not on that list, and there are no references to it in the git source code.)  They all start with `"GIT_"` except for `EMAIL`.

I'd list them here, but it's probably more useful to run `man git` yourself, to make sure you have the right list for the version you're using.

Answer (score 3):

git config --help and git config -l can also be of use for related reasons.